# Append a token list to \everymath

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

I've mimicked Donald Knuth by setting `|` as a verbatim delimiter. To give it its normal meaning in math mode, I've set

```
\everymath{\catcode`\|=12}
\everydisplay{\catcode`\|=12}
```

However I'd like to *append* this to `\everymath` instead of erasing its previous content (if any). I've tried

```
\everymath{a}
\everymath{\the\everymath b}
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

PS: this question is for plain TeX.

Comment: ConTeXt provides macros `\appendtoks` and `\prependtoks` for such tasks. You can use `\appendtoks b \to \everymath` to achieve what you want. There must be something equivalent in LaTeX; if not, you can always copy the ConTeXt definitions.

Comment: @Aditya it wasn't explicit in my question but I'm looking for a solution for plain TeX. Do you know where I can find the definition of \appendtoks?

Comment: Have you tried something like: `\expandafter\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath b}`.  Seems to work for me in everything but display mathmode.

Comment: @A.Ellett Nice! It doesn't work in display math since display math put the `\everydisplay` token list. `\everymath` works for non-display math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method won't work: if you have, say,

```
\section{Proof that $|x|\ge 0$}
```

the setting of `` \catcode`|=12 `` wouldn't take effect, because `|` would have already been tokenized.

The safest way is to say

```
\catcode`|=\active
\protected\def|{\ifmmode\expandafter\vert\else\expandafter\activebar\fi}

\def\activebar{...<whatever you want>...}
```

If you want to use Plain TeX without e-TeX extensions, the resulting command would be quite fragile, so use with care:

```
\def|{\relax\ifmmode\expandafter\vert\else\expandafter\activebar\fi}
```

(you find the reason for `\relax` in the TeXbook).

---

Let's try a Plain TeX document:

```
\input manmac
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\catcode`|=12 }
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\catcode`|=12 }

\beginsection $|x|$ is never negative.

|the $p$-norm| is
$$
\Vert x\Vert=\root p\of{|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p}
$$
\bye
```

You get

```
! Argument of \\ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   }
```

because `|` has already been tokenized when the argument of `\beginsection` was being absorbed.

With

```
\input manmac

\let\manmacbar| % after manmac | is active
\protected\def|{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\vert
  \else
    \expandafter\manmacbar
  \fi
}

\beginsection $|x|$ is never negative.

|the $p$-norm| is
$$
\Vert x\Vert=\root p\of{|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p}
$$
\bye
```

you get no error and the output is what's expected:

[image]

Comment: `\protected` is not a plain tex command.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's an e-TeX primitive; if `pdftex` is used, it's available.

Comment: Why do we need `\protected` there?

Comment: @HenriMenke With a simple `\def`, if `|` is used as the first item in an `\halign` based construction, it would be evaluated as if in text, not in math. A `\relax` before `\ifmmode` could do for this particular case, but the resulting macro would be fragile (not surviving `\edef`).

Answer (score 4):

A. Ellet gave the answer in the comments (edit: only one `\expandafter` is needed):

```
\everymath{a}
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath b}
```

sets `\everymath` to `ab`

Comment: You only need one `\expandafter`: the first one can be omitted.