# Replace backtick ` with power/caret ^ in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'd like to declare the backtick symbol `` ` `` to be the math operation power `^`, so that by writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \DeclareMathSymbol{`}{\mathbin}{symbols}{^}
\begin{document}
$3`2$
\end{document}
```

it is displayed
[image]

I was thinking to use `\DeclareMathSymbol{<symbol>}{<type>}{<sym-font>}{<slot>}` but I'm not sure there is a slot code for `^` since it is an operation rather than a symbol.

I'd like to avoid using `\newcommand` because otherwise I will have to write `` 3\`2 `` in order to get the power.

## PAINLESS SOLUTION

Install the lightweight program autohotkey and create a script with the following code

```
NumLock::
send {^}
return
```

once run, you can print the caret symbol `^` by pressing the Num Lock key in the numpad.

You can change NumLock to whatever you want, check the [list of all keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) and the [list of all hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), for example

```
MButton::     middle/wheel mouse button
^p::          ctrl+p
+p::          shift+p
F2::          F2
```

Comment: If you want to live dangerously: `\documentclass{article}
\let\oldbacktick\`
\catcode\`\`=\active
\protected\def\`{\ifmmode\expandafter^\else\expandafter\oldbacktick\fi}
\begin{document}
$3\`2$ a\`b
\end{document}` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151290)).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?  Is it simply to avoid hitting the shift key?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes i know i'm lazy but i'm going to type thousands of `^`, i solved with a small autohotkey script which prints `^` when i press NumLock

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of this is really *not* recommended, unless you really know what you are doing and/or is willing to suffer the consequences. In the words of Mr. Cat, this is "living dangerously", and you may end up being dead when someone opens the box ;-)

`\DeclareMathSymbol` is used to select the glyph in a font which will be used to write a specific symbol on the paper. The superscript happens in a much lower level in TeX. Usually, the `^` symbol has the [category code (catcode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3336/134574) 7, which is a "superscript token". This means that whenever TeX sees a `^`, it will make a superscript. At the simplest, you can have that effect by changing the catcode of a `` ` `` to 7:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\`=7
\begin{document}
$3`2$ and some `quoted' text
\end{document}
```

however, the code above will raise a `Missing $ inserted` because now that `` ` `` is a superscript character, it is only meant to be used in math-mode. You can redefine `` \` `` to mean a "normal" (catcode 12) `` ` `` character:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\`{`}
\catcode`\`=7
\begin{document}
$3`2$ and some \`quoted' text
\end{document}
```

and then you won't be able to write a grave accent with, say, `` D\'ej\`a vu `` (the output will be "Déj‘a vu"). Plus, any code which relies on `` ` `` being a catcode-12 token will fail miserably.

A arguably better alternative is to make the `` ` `` an active character *only* in math-mode and define it equal to a superscript token:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
{\catcode`\`=\active
 \global\let`=^}
\mathcode`\`="8000
\begin{document}
$3`2$ and some `quoted' text
\end{document}
```

the output is:

> [image]

But again, this might break something, somewhere, which relies on `` ` `` being a catcode 12 token.

Comment: Hmmh, I was hoping that you would refer to my code as "cat code". ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat LOL! How could I miss that? :-)

Comment: Related: [Let ' print a straight quote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521479/22016)

Comment: Any examples of package that this code would break, or other problems arising due to the change of catcode?

Comment: @OlivierCailloux The third alternative is rather safe, as no catcode is changed and only the meaning of the symbol in math-mode is affected. The first two, however, will break anything that relies on `\`` being a catcode-12 character. The backtick is especially bad. Just try `\usepackage{etoolbox}` (for example) after changing the catcode of `\`` to 7.