# How to use backticks as a \tt mode

Tags: typewriter, latex-misc

Using markdown quite a lot lately, I would like to use backticks/backquotes in the same way in Latex. Thus

```
Using a `tt-font`
```

would produce the same as

```
Using a {\tt tt-font}
```

similarly to the two `$`s to enable [math-mode](/questions/tagged/math-mode).

I am aware that [such changes are problematic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504960/replace-backtick-with-power-caret-in-math-mode) as the [tex-core](/questions/tagged/tex-core) uses backticks for character codes, but I do not use these directly in my files.

Comment: Perhaps you should simply use the `markdown` package if you prefer to use the Markdown syntax with LaTeX.

Comment: @Gaussler, thank you, from what [I gathered](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown), this package supports full markdown, so one then cannot use the regular latex commands,

Comment: The package supports a hybrid mode where both Markdown and LaTeX syntax can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that `\tt` (together with all two-letter font change commands) has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Now your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=``\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\markdownbackquote
  \catcode``=\active
}
\begingroup
\catcode``=\active
\protected\gdef\markdownbackquote#1`{\texttt{#1}}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

This is `typewriter` type.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The preamble code might also be

```
\begingroup
\catcode``=\active
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let`\markdownbackquote
  \expandafter\catcode\string``=\active
}
\protected\gdef\markdownbackquote#1`{\texttt{#1}}
\endgroup
```

Comment: deprecated since 30 years? What is the recommended way then?

Comment: @user1778602 `\texttt{...}`

Comment: ... thank you, but how can I use unescaped underscored within the backticks?

Comment: @false Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Such that I can write a name with underscores directly. Currently, I need to insert a `\` everywhere.

Comment: @false That's an altogether different problem. Look for “underscore” in the site and you'll find what you need.

Comment: What I need is in the 2nd sentence: *I would like to use backticks/backquotes in the same* (markdown) *way in Latex.* Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @false Just do ``\catcode`_=12`` and ``\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}``, but this has nothing to do with backquotes as described in your question.